# Preventing app from resuming from other than the MainActivity

Tags: android

Let's say there are two activities in my app: MainActivity, Activity2. If the user navigates to Activity2, presses the home button, and a long time later, opens my app again.

The app resumes from Activity2. This is kind of app's restart, but from Activity2. The Activity2's states are restored, but MainActivity has not been created yet. Can I, in this case, prevent the app from resuming from Activity2, but make it start from MainActivity, just as if the user has launched the app again?

The reason is that some initialisations are done in the MainActivity (which can be moved to Application), and Activity2 was launched with the data from MainActivity, and the data is outdated after a long while, so it is not desirable to start from Activity2 after a long time.

Comment: In that case, you can `finish()` the `Activity2` in the `onPause` lifecycle method. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
     finish();
     }
```

Comment: This is not something I wanted, but since it seems to be no better way, I will take this as the answer. I mean, what I wanted was to prevent the app from starting (resuming is basically starting with saved state) from non-main activity, not closing the second activity whenever the user leaves and comes back. It could be that a user left the app only for a minute to answer a phone call. Closing the second activity for that is wrong, I think.